# Statistics to detect employee/customer collusion

Tags: distributions, business-intelligence

I'm an analyst at an agency that operates landfills.  There was a recent discovery that certain trash haulers colluded with 2 or 3 weigh-masters to undercharge in return for kickbacks.  I'm tasked with developing a metric that measures the likeliness of collusion based on the frequency that each hauler is weighed by each weigh-master.  The weighing process is similar to a supermarket with multiple check-out lines.  The customer (hauler) is free to choose any check-out line.  Normally the customer would choose the shortest line. However if a customer, most of the time, selects the line of one specific cashier (weigh-master), then collusion would be suspected.  In my dataset, I have the number of transactions by each weigh-master for each customer (in a specified period of time).  My question is, for example, if one weigh-master conducted 25% of the transactions overall (in a month) but one customer frequented that particular weigh-master 50% of the time (12 transactions out of 24 total) what is likelihood that this occurred by random chance (not collusion)? Assume the one weigh-master was on-duty during each of the 24 transactions, but was chosen by the one customer 12 times.  And at the times of the 24 transactions, the one weigh-master handled 25% of the total transaction volume.

Comment: As this appears to be a real world problem, real world issues interfere with there being a short answer.  For instance, scheduling.  Maybe one weigh-master only handled $10\%$ of the cases, but his hours happened to coincide exactly with a driver's regular route.  There needs to be some sort of control in place to guard against this sort of stray statistical interference.

Comment: Yes, this a simplified question.  I was planning to do separate analyses for each shift.

Comment: But of course, I just picked one possible sort of statistical interference.  In practice, while one tries to think of as many sources of bias as possible, there's always a strong chance that bias remains.  Therefore, people run controls.  Here, it would be good if you could run trucks known to be honest through the same 
 system.  Then compare the unknowns to those knowns.

Comment: Medical studies always have large control groups.  People who experience all the same things the actual test pool experiences, though they do not receive the treatment being evaluated.  That's the sort of thing I mean.

Comment: It's also possible that a driver, just out of habit and for no particular reason, always chooses, say, the first line on the right. Or even that they choose the longest line (maybe the driver is paid by the hour, including time spent waiting in line, so this maximizes the time the driver gets paid for doing nothing).

Comment: For the known frauds, it appears the dishonest customers conducted their business mostly only when the conspiring weigh-masters were on duty.  So perhaps just looking at trucks with a frequency of transactions with one weigh-master would identify most future collusions.

Comment: lulu: thanks for the tips.  We have a pretty good idea who the honest and dishonest customers and employees were based on other types of data. So we're monitoring other known indicators as well.  And we can use the known data to develop threshold percentage levels.  Perhaps it's not necessary to do a statistical analysis.  As you mentioned there are many variables, and it would be complicated.

Comment: Robert, yes I believe this does occur. But I would assume not very often.  I'm simply looking for a practical metric that could be used perhaps one a month to deliver an automated alert when one one or more weigh-masters/customers reaches a certain threshold, such as 95% confidence that the frequency of choosing the same scale operator x out of y times would not happen by chance.  Just a screening tool to initiate further investigation.

Comment: Do you have data on how often each weigh-master was available to be chosen by each hauler?

Comment: Dimitriy, yes, that's how I arranged the data.  I'm looking at each weigh-master separately, and including only those transactions that occurred while the one weigh-master was on duty.  So for example during a one month period, while Bob was on-duty, truck XYZ123 dumped 15 times.  10 of the 15 times he used Bob's scale.  Bob conducted 26% of the transactions while he was on-duty.  My assumption earlier was that each truck chooses the shortest line or the next available open scale.  If that were the case, then there should be a 26% chance he'll choose Bob's scale each time. (continued)

Comment: Then the probability of this occurring randomly I assume would fit a binomial distribution. However, in reality I'm noticing that individual trucks favor certain scales (even though collusion is not suspected). Also, the weigh-masters are not regularly rotated to different scales.  I'm going to recommend that weigh-masters be rotated (preferably at random) to each of the scales. So if some trucks favor certain scales, at least the weigh-masters would be randomized.  If that were done, do you think a binomial cumulative distribution function is appropriate?